# Sharepoint 2010 workflows via VS2010 - really need server installed locally?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I went to create a SP2010 Workflow project in VS2010, and it complained that I did not have SP Server installed on my machine.

Well, I do not want to install SP2010 on my dev machine.  I have a perfectly good dev instance installed onto a VM.

Is it possible at all to design SP 2010 workflow projects in VS2010 without having a local instance of Sharepoint?

Cheers,

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like the answer is "No, you must have SP2010 installed locally"

Answer (score 0):

Will VS let you continue after receiving that message?

Microsoft recommendation is to install Visual Studio on the your DEV VM (running Windows Server 2008 R2) that has SharePoint running.  You'll also get additional debug features by doing this, like F5 debugging/breakpoints, and auto deploy/retract of your solutions.

Comment: I believe you can install SP2010 on a Windows 7 box.

Comment: You can, its supported but not recommended.  Either way, if you install SharePoint 2010 and VS 2010 on the same machine, your development experience will be much richer.

Comment: I guess their recommendation is to use Server 2008 in a VM - nice, if you can do it.

Comment: No, after the message VS exits the new project dialog and does not continue.

Comment: Have you tried installing Visual Studio on your Dev VM to see if the issue persists there?